# What error or exceptions do I need to look out for when programming with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, network-programming

I am a bit new at network programming. I currently am working on an app using python that sends and receives data when it accepts a connection. Assuming the hardware is good, what situations and error should I test for so I can mitigate them.

I already have tested for Non-blocking operation not completed, host unreachable, connection aborted, connection refused, and connection reset.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Quote from python 2.7 doc "All errors raise exceptions. The normal exceptions for invalid argument types and out-of-memory conditions can be raised; errors related to socket or address semantics raise the error socket.error."

Comment: I know that it raises socket error, but from socket error it can be beause of a variety of different reasons and it was expanded on os.error. So many of the error will unlikely to ever been raised. For example a hardware error  or socket does not support error is unlikely to be raised after a connection has been established.

Comment: Hardware error can happen any time, as well as e.g. memory error

Comment: @user3346931: you don't need to know what `socket.error` it is; unless you want to handle it differently from other exceptions with the same type and in this case you will know what the error is e.g., "timeout" error, EINTR, or EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. Specific errors may also be platform-dependent.

Comment: Since the app is mainly just running on a linux system (raspberry pi to be more exact), I am not too concern about platform-dependent errors.

I am not too concern about hardware problems also.